# ¿Cómo traduzco XL y otras abreviaciones de las tallas?

Tags: traducción, abreviaturas, ropa

En inglés, existen abreviaciones comunes de las tallas.  Por ejemplo, **XL** significa "*Extra Large*" y **S** significa "*Small*".

¿Existen unas abreviaciones idiomáticas en español para las tallas?  Y si quiero traducir estas abreviaciones, ¿cómo debo hacer eso?

No quiero conjeturar y escribir **XG** (significando "Extra Grande"), porque si alguien escribió **VB** (significando "*Very Big*") en inglés, no sabría qué es eso, porque no es idiomático.

Comment: Correcciones de mi español extraño serán agradecidas.

Answer (score 4):

Yo he visto en tiendas P de pequeño, M de mediano, G de grande y XP de extra pequeño (nótese que es X y no E), XG no caigo en haberlo visto. Hablo de experiencia en España, aunque también se suele ver XL, L, M, S, XS, sobre todo en grandes multinacionales (Zara). Como comentario, discutimos una vez si una M en Reino Unido era una M en España, y resultó que una M en Reino Unido, era por lo general una L en España y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 4):

En España siempre he visto las abreviaturas inglesas de las tallas: XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, etc.

La verdad que nunca he visto XP o EP (Extra pequeño), ni XG o EG (Extra grande).

La gente en general está acostumbrada a las abreviaturas en ingles por lo que creo que son las más recomendables.

Answer (score 1):

En EEUU se escriben igual; cuando van de compras, los hispanoparlantes generalmente dicen

- Triple Equis
- XX ("equis equis") (o Extra Extra Grande)
- XL ("equis ele") o X (o Extra Grande)
- Grande
- Mediano
- Pequeño
- Extra Pequeño

Comment: ¿Existen abreviaciones de grande y mediano y pequeño o esas palavras siempre son dejadas como están?

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic - Creo que he visto alguna vez P, M, G.  A ver qué dicen los europeos.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic: [Aquí](https://www.dyneke.com/tallaje) tienes un ejemplo. Pero muchas veces se usan también en España las letras que has indicado en tu pregunta y se nombran como ha explicado aparente001. De hecho, una vez, en un concierto de música de cámara (creo que de un compositor barroco), oí decir por megafonía: algo así como "Hay un cambio en el programa: en lugar de la sonata equis ele, ..." y en ese momento pensé ¡tierra, trágame! Por lo visto empieza a haber gente más familiarizada con este sistema de tallaje que con los números romanos.

Answer (score 1):

En la Wikipedia me he encontrado esta tabla de equivalencias:

- XXS extra extra pequeño
- XS extra pequeño
- S pequeño
- M mediano
- L grande
- XL extra grande
- XXL extra extra grande
- XXXL extra extra extra grande

---

**Referencias**

[Norma EN 13402](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EN_13402)